# How to pass value of names in struct array as reference in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, pass-by-reference

im supposed to be able to print all of the countries in the printfunction and pass it to the second if statement, but it doesn't seem to be printing . I know it's the

> printf("%s\n", ctryList[numCountries].countryName);

part but i don't know what's wrong with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

const int MAX_COUNTRY_NAME_LENGTH = 50;

typedef struct CountryTvWatch_struct {
   char countryName[50];
   int tvMinutes;
} CountryTvWatch;

void PrintCountryNames(CountryTvWatch ctryList[], int numCountries)
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < numCountries; i++)
   {
   printf("%s\n", ctryList[numCountries].countryName); 
   }
   return;
} 

int main(void) {
   // Source: www.statista.com, 2010
   const int NUM_COUNTRIES = 4;

   CountryTvWatch countryList[NUM_COUNTRIES];
   char countryToFind[MAX_COUNTRY_NAME_LENGTH];
   bool countryFound = false;
   int i = 0;

   strcpy(countryList[0].countryName, "Brazil");
   countryList[0].tvMinutes = 222; 
   strcpy(countryList[1].countryName, "India");       
   countryList[1].tvMinutes = 119;
   strcpy(countryList[2].countryName, "U.K.");        
   countryList[2].tvMinutes = 242;
   strcpy(countryList[3].countryName, "U.S.A.");      
   countryList[3].tvMinutes = 283;

   printf("Enter country name: \n");
   scanf("%s", countryToFind);

   countryFound = false;
   for (i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTRIES; ++i) { // Find country's index
      if (strcmp(countryList[i].countryName, countryToFind) == 0) {
         countryFound = true;
         printf("People in %s watch\n", countryToFind);
         printf("%d minutes of TV daily.\n", countryList[i].tvMinutes);
      }
   }
   if (!countryFound) {
      printf("Country not found, try again.\n");
      printf("Valid countries:\n"); 
      PrintCountryNames(countryList, NUM_COUNTRIES); 
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ctryList[numCountries]` does not exist; the array `ctryList` only has `ctryList[0]`, `ctryList[1]`, ..., up to `ctryList[numCountries-1]`. You probably want to print `ctryList[i].countryName`.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 50.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  The posted code does have a `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, but is not using the meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' format specifier, always include a MAX_CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input field a) to avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior b) to allow room for NUL byte that will be appended to the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. incorporates the comments to the question
2. properly checks for I/O errors
3. lets the user know what countries are available to chose from
4. is appropriately spaced, both horizontally and vertically, for readability
5. performs the desired functionality
6. cleanly compiles
7. documents why each header file is included

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>     // scanf(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h>    // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>    // strcmp()
#include <stdbool.h>   // bool, true, false

#define MAX_COUNTRY_NAME_LENGTH  50
#define NUM_COUNTRIES  4

struct CountryTvWatch_struct
{
    char countryName[ MAX_COUNTRY_NAME_LENGTH ];
    int tvMinutes;
};
typedef struct CountryTvWatch_struct CountryTvWatch;


// prototypes
void PrintCountryNames( CountryTvWatch ctryList[], int numCountries );


int main(void)
{
   // Source: www.statista.com, 2010

   CountryTvWatch countryList[NUM_COUNTRIES];
   char countryToFind[ MAX_COUNTRY_NAME_LENGTH+1];

   strcpy(countryList[0].countryName, "Brazil");
   countryList[0].tvMinutes = 222;

   strcpy(countryList[1].countryName, "India");
   countryList[1].tvMinutes = 119;

   strcpy(countryList[2].countryName, "U.K.");
   countryList[2].tvMinutes = 242;

   strcpy(countryList[3].countryName, "U.S.A.");
   countryList[3].tvMinutes = 283;

   // let user know what countries are available and how they are spelled
   PrintCountryNames(countryList, NUM_COUNTRIES);

   printf("Enter country name: \n");

   // Note: following statement 
   //     checks for error
   //     includes a MAX_CHAR modifier that is one less than
   //    the length of the input field
   if( 1 != scanf("%49s", countryToFind) )
   {
       perror( "scanf failed" );
       exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
   }

   // implied else, scanf successful


   bool countryFound = false;

   for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTRIES; ++i )
   { // Find country's index
      if (strcmp(countryList[i].countryName, countryToFind) == 0)
      {
         countryFound = true;
         printf("People in %s watch\n", countryToFind);
         printf("%d minutes of TV daily.\n", countryList[i].tvMinutes);
         break;  // exit the search loop early
      }
   }

   if (!countryFound)
   {
      printf("Country not found, try again.\n");
      printf("Valid countries:\n");
      PrintCountryNames(countryList, NUM_COUNTRIES);
   }

   return 0;
}


void PrintCountryNames( CountryTvWatch ctryList[], int numCountries )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < numCountries; i++ )
    {
        printf("%s\n", ctryList[ i ].countryName);
    }
}
```